# Windows 7 connect to network before startup process and login

Tags: windows, networking, startup, winlogon

I have the following problem. I developed a script that must be executed prior to login in Windows 7. This script must, among other things, authenticate with a given Internet host and save the return into a txt file. The problem is that when the script is initiated, it could not find network connectivity and the authentication just fails.

To add the script to startup I followed this tutorial: [connect to VPN before logging into windows](http://htipe.wordpress.com/2010/02/11/connect-to-vpn-before-logging-in-to-windows/)

I've already tried to enable "Always wait for the network at startup and logon" in Computer Configuration/Administrative Templates/System/Logon in gpedit.msc, but it is not working.

Have anyone faced a problem like that? Any hints? I just want to force the wired network to be fully ready and working before running the startup scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.  I found it on another forum.

In the Local Group Policy Editor go to `Computer Configuration -> Administrative Templates -> System -> Group Policy -> set Startup policy processing wait time` to `120`.

For some reason the "Always wait for the network at computer startup and logon" doesn't always work, it seems like it was just a matter of timing. About 80% of the time I would get an error of "no domain controllers available". The added delay of the "Startup policy processing wait time" made it so the autologin always works.